# Yum reports updated bash but binary still reports old version

Tags: centos, bash, centos5, exploit

I'm trying to update a CentOS 5 system in order to patch the bash vulnerability described in [CVE-2014-6271](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2014-6271) / [RHSA-2014:1293-1](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-1293.html), but am running into an issue.

After seemingly-successfully updating bash via `yum update bash` and restarting the server, `yum list bash` lists the installed version as patched (3.2.33.e15.1) but `/bin/bash --version` is displaying 3.2.25(1)-release.

By all accounts (via `rpm -ql bash`), the binary location is correct and `find / -name bash` only returns that one location.

Any thoughts as to why the version discrepancy might be occuring?

Comment: $ rpm -q --changelog bash |more
* Mon Sep 15 2014 Ondrej Oprala <ooprala@redhat.com> - 3.2-33.1
- Check for fishy environment
  Resolves: #1141644

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that, despite the version discrepancy, the update was successful. Running the sample input succeeds where it did not before:

```
user [~]# env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `x'
this is a test
```

Comment: There is no version discrepancy - this is backporting in action.

Answer (score 3):

At Red Hat they usually patch older versions instead of directly updating to the newest ones so as not to break any systems. Since this is just a vulnerability patch it ensures that the binary and the whole package remains backwards compatible.

You can use `rpm` to inspect the changelog for the package. This way you can always verify if you're using the newest backported version.

`# rpm -q --changelog <the rpm package that just got installed>`